# Getting rid of variant constructors

Tags: ocaml, variant

As a side project, I try to implement the basics of an RDF library in OCaml.

As you may (or may not) know, a RDF statement (or triple) is composed of 3 parts:

- The *subject* can be an IRI or a blank node;
- The *predicate* must be an IRI;
- The *object* can be an IRI, a blank node or a literal.

I have module and types for IRIs, blank nodes and literals, and in order to type-proof the rules described above, here is what I've started to write:

```
(* In `triple.ml` *)
type subject = Iri of Iri.t | Bnode of Bnode.t
type objekt = Iri of Iri.t | Bnode of Bnode.t | Literal of Literal.t

type t = subject * Iri.t * objekt

let create s p o = s, p, o
```

So this is nice and everything, but one thing grinds my gears: whenever I want to use `Triple.create`, I must explicitly state the constructor of the variant:

```
let iri = (* Some Iri.t value *) in
let literal = (* Literal.t value *) in
Triple.create (Iri iri) iri (Literal literal)
```

I'm pretty sure OCaml has ways to work around that, but I'm not sure how.

Some thoughts: I could parameterize the `Triple.t` type with the type of its subject and the type of its object, but then how do I enforce the restrictions on the parameter types? Or maybe it is a good use case for a GADT?

Comment: Reading back [this article](https://mads-hartmann.com/ocaml/2015/01/05/gadt-ocaml.html) I had found a while back, it seems that GADT is the way to go here. I've never used them before, so this should be interesting.

Comment: Not sure, maybe you can use inheritance instead of GADTs. I've never used OOP in Ocaml though.

Comment: It looks like the example should be `Triple.create (Iri iri) iri (Literal literal)` for it to have type `t`.

Comment: Here I recommend using a record rather than a tuple. There's no downside to it since you have a type definition already. It also has the advantage of being easily extensible (you can add a field without breaking too much code) and it's easy to access just one field without having to know about the position or number of other fields.

Comment: Another small remark: I'd use `object_` instead of `objekt` because the same rule can be used systematically for all keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind changing the types of `Iri.t`, etc, you could do something like this (replacing `internal = string` with the real type in each case):

```
module Iri : sig
  type internal
  type t = [`Iri of internal]
  val v : string -> [> t]
end = struct
  type internal = string
  type t = [`Iri of internal]
  let v x = `Iri x
end

module Bnode : sig
  type internal
  type t = [`Bnode of internal]
  val v : string -> [> t]
end = struct
  type internal = string
  type t = [`Bnode of internal]
  let v x = `Bnode x
end

module Literal : sig
  type internal
  type t = [`Literal of internal]
  val v : string -> [> t]
end = struct
  type internal = string
  type t = [`Literal of internal]
  let v x = `Literal x
end

module Triple = struct
  type subject = [Iri.t | Bnode.t]
  type objekt = [Iri.t | Bnode.t | Literal.t]

  type t = subject * Iri.t * objekt

  let v s p o : t = s, p, o
end

let alice = Iri.v "alice"
let knows = Iri.v "knows"
let bob = Iri.v "bob"

let x1 = Bnode.v "blank-x1"

let foo = Literal.v "foo"

let triple1 = Triple.v alice knows bob
let triple2 = Triple.v bob knows x1
let triple3 = Triple.v bob knows foo
```

Note that in the example at the end, the same value `bob` is used both as a subject (`[Iri.t | Bnode.t]`) and as an object (`[Iri.t | Bnode.t | Literal.t]`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is very helpful. For `Bnode` and `Literal`, it works like a charm. For `Iri` however, I simply include the `Uri` module from the [ocaml-uri](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-uri) package (details [here](https://github.com/Richard-Degenne/ocaml-rdf/tree/dev/lib)). Is there a way to connect the library with this new type definition without having to redefine everything?

Comment: You'd have to set `Iri.internal = Uri.t` (and users would need to use `Iri.v uri` to create an `Iri` from a `Uri.t`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you can fully achieve this even with GADT. What will be the type of `create` in this case? First argument must be either `Iri.t` or `Bnode.t` unless one is a subtype of another, you can't write such function (or it will be very general: `'a -> ...`).

In any case you need to provide a type of the arguments. What you can do with GADT is to "move" the information about the types into another type:

```
type 'a rdf_ty = II : (Iri.t   * Iri.t)     rdf_ty |
                 BI : (Bnode.t * Iri.t)     rdf_ty |
                 IB : (Iri.t   * Bnode.t)   rdf_ty |
                 BB : (Bnode.t * Bnode.t)   rdf_ty |
                 IL : (Iri.t   * Literal.t) rdf_ty |
                 BL : (Bnode.t * Literal.t) rdf_ty
```

`rdf_ty` encode the types of the first and third arguments of `create`:

```
type t = subject * Iri.t * objekt

let create : type a b. (a * b) rdf_ty -> a -> Iri.t -> b -> t = fun ty s p o ->
    match ty with
    | II -> Iri s, p, Iri o
    | BI -> Bnode s, p, Iri o
    | IB -> Iri s, p, Bnode o
    | BB -> Bnode s, p, Bnode o
    | IL -> Iri s, p, Literal o
    | BL -> Bnode s, p, Literal o

let iri = (* Some Iri.t value *) in
let literal = (* Literal.t value *) in
create IL iri iri literal
```

But I really doubt that this is a better version than the original one.

Comment: Yeah, I tried toying around with GADT, and I came to the same conclusions as you.

Comment: GADTs don't eliminate any Constructors but add more strict type requirements. GADTs would only make sense if the types had some dependencies, e.g. subject and object must both be Iri or both be Bnode and such.